# What Type of Initialization Occurs When Calling Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, copy-constructor, list-initialization

Consider the simple struct below (defaulted just to be explicit).

```
struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) = default;
};

foo bar() {
    return foo{}; // return does copy init
}
```

What kind of initializations take place below?

```
foo a;        // default init
foo b{};      // value initialization
foo c{bar()}; // ?? mandatory copy elision. is this considered direct init? so copy init to return from 
              // bar(), then direct init to init c?
foo d{c};     // ?? copy constructor called. is this considered direct init or copy init?
foo e = d;    // copy init
```

Looking for answers for C++ 17. Please provide references whenever applicable.
Thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `foo c{bar()};`, `c` is [direct-list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) from the return value of `bar()`. And it's same for `foo d{c};`, `d` is direct-list-initialized from `c`.

> 1. initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list (that is, a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested braced-init-lists)

As the effect, for `foo c{bar()};`, because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17) the copy construction in the `return` statement and the initialization of `c` are omitted, `c` is constructed by the default constructor directly. For `foo d{c};`, the copy constructor is selected to construct `d`.

BTW: In `bar()`, `return foo{};` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), because of mandatory copy elision (since C++17) the copy construction is omitted, the return value is initialized by the default constructor directly (since C++20). (Until C++20 it'll be [aggregate-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).)

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn’t `return foo{};` using _aggregate initialization_, as `foo` is an aggregate (at least until C++20). I belive you can explicitly delete _all_ constructors of `foo` while still keeping `return foo{};` well-formed in C++17 (guaranteed copy elision combined with the fact that `foo` even with deleted ctors is an aggregate until C++20).

Comment: (See [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf) for the C++20 change that removes this aggregate peculiarity).

Comment: @dfri I got what you mean. Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

> What Type of Initialization Occurs When Calling Copy Constructor?

Your question is backwards and ultimately unanswerable.

Initialization forms determine the various steps used to take the initializer expressions and initialize an object from them. There are many forms of initialization, and most of them have some mechanism that can ultimately lead to a copy constructor call. List initialization, direct initialization, copy initialization, aggregate initialization, all of these *could* call the copy constructor, given the right initializer, of course.

As such, you cannot know which initialization form was used *solely* from the fact that a copy constructor was called.

The form of initialization used is determined by the syntax that initializes the object.

```
foo c{bar()};
foo d{c};
```

These use the same initialization syntax, so they use the same form of initialization. This is direct-initialization, but because the initializer is a braced-init-list (`{}`), that will quickly become direct-list-initialization.

```
foo e = d;
```

This syntax invokes copy initialization.